@Async annotation throwing errors in micronaut
I am trying to setup a basic micronaut project. I want to use the @Async annotation to run asynchronous processes. This is my current project structure :
├── aot-jar.properties
├── micronaut-cli.yml
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── com
│   │   │       └── micronautexample
│   │   │           ├── Application.java
│   │   │           └── Controller
│   │   │               ├── SampController.java
│   │   │               └── SampService.java
│   │   └── resources
│   │       ├── application.yml
│   │       └── logback.xml

I'm injecting SampService into SampController, and invoking sleep().
@Slf4j
@Singleton
public class SampService {

    @Async(TaskExecutors.BLOCKING)
    public void sleep() {
        log.info("SLeeping");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("E");
        }
        log.info("Wake");
    }
}

The issue I'm facing is, when I run the application I'm getting this error
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: failed to access class com.micronautexample.Controller.$SampService$Definition$Intercepted from class com.micronautexample.$Controller.$SampService$Definition$Intercepted$Definition (com.micronautexample.Controller.$SampService$Definition$Intercepted and com.micronautexample.$Controller.$SampService$Definition$Intercepted$Definition are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at com.micronautexample.$Controller.$SampService$Definition$Intercepted$Definition.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.allocateInstance(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.DirectMethodHandle.allocateInstance(DirectMethodHandle.java:520)
    at io.micronaut.core.io.service.SoftServiceLoader.lambda$collectDynamicServices$2(SoftServiceLoader.java:189)
    ... 7 more

If I comment out the @Async annotation, it works fine. Moreover, if I move both the service and the controller from the child package Controller to com.micronautexample, @Async works fine as well. I'm not able to figure out why it fails in this specific scenario. Any help is appreciated, thanks

What happens if you rename Controller package to controller? Using upper-case characters in the package name does not follow a naming convention.

Hi, looks like that was it. I was just trying to create a sample and didn't pay too much attention to the package names. Thanks a lot @SzymonStepniak

did you enable the "BLOCKING" executor in the application.yml?
